# Generalization of Levy-Solovay theorem to kappa-c.c. forcings

Tags: set-theory, forcing

The Levy-Solovay theorem says that if $\kappa$ is measurable, then it remains measurable in the extension by a small forcing ($|\mathbb{P}|<\kappa$). Is still true if we replace $|\mathbb{P}|<\kappa$ with "$\mathbb{P}$ has the $\lambda-\textrm{c.c.}$ for some $\lambda<\kappa$"? Or even, can a c.c.c. forcing destroy measurability of $\kappa$?

This conjecture seems to check out with all the natural examples of forcings that I know.

Drake

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The forcing to add $\kappa$ many Cohen reals is c.c.c and thereby preserves all cardinals but destroys the fact that $\kappa$ is even strongly inaccessible. (See for example Kunen "Set Theory: An Introduction to Independence Proofs" North-Holland, Ch. VII.)